# create DateComponents / NSDateComponents from String and vice versa

Tags: swift, date, healthkit, swift3

Is there an (elegant or preferred) way to convert a DateComponents object to a String and back so that

```
DateComponents -> String -> DateComponents
```

is alway possible and the resulting object equals the original object? (not identical) (like `CustomStringRepresentable`)

For `NSDate` / `Date` there is an `NSDateFormatter` / `DateFormatter` that is able to do this trick, converting back and forth.

For `DateComponents` there is a `DateComponentsFormatter`, but it appears to me not to support the direction from `String` to `DateComponents`.

**motivation for this question**

HealthKit used to store birthdays as `NSDate` up to iOS 9.x.

Starting with iOS 10, HealthKit uses `DateComponents` as a model for birthdays. (And deprecated `NSDate` for birthdays)

I'm trying to reflect HealthKits model change in my own data model of a HealthKit centric app. The most straight forward is to use `DateComponents` in my model as HealthKit does.

As I need to save my model to a file and load it again, the answer to this question would enable me to do this.

The obvious fallback is to convert `DateComponents` to `Date` and save that. But there must be a good reason why Apple deprecated `Date` for birthdays.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the relation between the components and the string respectively the string format.

Comment: I don't care very much about the String format. Anything that works. Would be nice if it was readable by a developer for debugging reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the date components directly via `NSKeyedArchiver` since `NSDateComponents` conforms to `NS(Secure)Coding`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I added the motivation to my question because of your answer to show that date calculations are not the problem. It is to find a string representation of the data Apple gives to me.

Comment: Sorry for that but you didn't describe the actual problem when you asked the question hours ago.

Comment: I asked how a DateComponents to be represented as a String and that String to DateComponents. I wasn't aware this would trigger "don't do that" answers. Sorry.

Comment: But where is the problem? The `(NS)Date` class is not deprecated at all. It's just the birthday representation that changed. So you could safely use my suggestion to convert `DateComponents` to `String` and vice versa.

Comment: Because DateComponents has a Calendar as part of its data model. This could change (HK says it uses Gregorian at the moment). And DateComponents can model dates in a way NSDate can't. As Date isn't deprecated, the reason for Apple must be that DateComponents can represent birthdays in a way Date can't. (though I don't know that reason)

Comment: By the way: `NSDateComponents` conforms to `NS(Secure)Coding` so you can save date components directly via `NSKeyedArchiver`

Comment: thats it and it works. Thanks :-) If you make this an answer I'll give you your thumbs up :-)

Comment: oops. data.base64EncodedString().length = 2488. But it works